# Store ascii into an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, ascii

I need to store the ASCII code of each character inputted by the user into an array, and then display the ASCII in the converted textbox

btw [here is my interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQddO.png)

---

these are my declarations

```
Dim modByte() As Integer 'the array where i need to put each ascii code
Dim modValue As String 'modvalue = mod_TB_Input.Text
```

this is the code i use to put the ascii into an array

```
For Each ch As Char In modValue 
        For Each i As Integer In modByte
            modByte(i) = Asc(ch)
            mod_TB_convert.Text = modByte(i) 'converted(textbox) = mod_tb_convert
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far? What part are you stuck at?

Comment: @JesseJ store ascii to modbyte(), and then show each modbyte() in the textbox.

sorry, i'm not good with arrays

Comment: I don't think you want to nest the for-loops. Do them separately. The first loop will establish modBytes. The second will re-construct the string. But also append the characters: `mod_TB_convert.Text += modByte(i)`.

Comment: @JerryM modByte is not getting the ascii code using these     modByte(i) = Asc(ch)

i'm having a null reference. 

PS. i can show the text in the textbox using these but what i really need is store the ascii in the modbyte()
<pre>    For Each ch As Char In modValue
            mod_TB_convert.Text = mod_TB_convert.Text & " " & Asc(ch)
        Next ch <code>

Comment: You can also use the [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get the ASCII byte values: `Dim modByte() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(modValue)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably build the array first then output...also your code isn't working, you need to redim preserve the array as it grows - e.g.

```
Dim modByte() As Integer
Dim modValue As String = mod_TB_Input.Text
Dim counter As Integer = 0

For Each ch As Char In modValue
  counter += 1
  ReDim Preserve modByte(counter - 1)
  modByte(counter - 1) = Asc(ch)
Next

mod_TB_convert.Text = String.Join("", modByte)
```

BUT - you can avoid all this and do it in one line...

```
mod_TB_convert.Text = String.Join("", mod_TB_Input.Text.Select(Function(t) Asc(t)))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works :)

it's the first time i encountered ReDim Preserve

Comment: no problem.  I'd also look into List<of T> - a lot easier than dealing with arrays